# C# oneline foreach loop in JS block breaks but same loop in mutiline works

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

In trying to fill a JavaScript array base off data in my ViewModel I noticed something odd. When I use the following code Visual Studio does not show any errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ChangeTypes = [],
        Priorities = [],
        ImpactTypes = [],
        Users = [];

    @foreach (var Type in Model.ChangeTypes)
    {
        @:ChangTypes.push("@Type");
    }

    alert(ChangeTypes);
</script>
```

but when I use the code below I get the error:

> The name "alert" does not exist in the current context"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ChangeTypes = [],
        Priorities = [],
        ImpactTypes = [],
        Users = [];

    @foreach (var Type in Model.ChangeTypes) { @:ChangTypes.push("@Type"); }

    alert(ChangeTypes);
</script>
```

What is it about going from that multiline version of the loop to a single line version that breaks the JavaScript?

As asked, if I run the project I get the error

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> /Views/ProjectManagement/ITChangeManagement.cshtml
>
> Encountered end tag "script" with no matching start tag. Are your
>   start/end tags properly balanced?

Edit:
 So interestingly enough the following code does not have any problems:

```
@foreach (var Status in Model.ApprovalStatus) { <text>ApprivalStatus.push("@Status");</text> }
```

Comment: What does the **output** look like in each case? E.g., what the browser actually sees?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder.  I bet nothing is broken.  The browser will process both just fine.  It is just his VS giving an incorrect warning.  (I almost said "his VS giving some BS")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can't get the HTML output as when I run the site IIS reports the error I have added to my post. So VS's warning is not a BS error but a real compilation error.

Comment: RAZOR is a nightmare sometimes.  It does weird things like this, and I really don't have a good explanation of why.  You might try using a @{ foreach ... } instead?

Comment: @Scottie `@{foreach..}` gives the same problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I wonder why you have ChangeTypes in your var definitions and ChangTypes in your foreach loop?  And if that has anything to do with the problem, both versions should fail.

Comment: @AgapwIesu It does not, I can change the name of the JS `ChangeTypes` array to anything and get the same problem.

Comment: Mathew, you might have missed the point of my comment.  The variable appears to have two different names in the code.  One is missing an the "e" in "Change".

Comment: @AgapwIesu I did miss the point, and the missing "e" but once corrected I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor uses the `@` to denote the start of a Razor directive. Unless you actively leave the scope of the directive, you stay within “Razor mode”.

Now, most directives end when their syntactic structure ends. For example `@Variable` ends when the part after it would no longer make a valid variable access. And `@foreach` ends after the opening brace and switches to “content mode”.

However, `@:` is special as it takes whatever comes after and interprets it as literal content. And it only ends with a line break.

So splitting it into multiple lines again, it would be equivalent to this

```
@foreach (var Type in Model.ChangeTypes)
{
    @:ChangTypes.push("@Type"); }

    alert(ChangeTypes);
    </script>
```

I have adjusted the indentation here to make clear what’s going on: There is no closing brace before the closing `script` tag, so that closing tag is still part of the content of the foreach—but there is no starting tag within the foreach body, so that’s where the syntax error comes from.

The solution with `<text> </text>` does not have this problem as the closing `text` tag tells Razor exactly where the content ends. So it does not interpret the closing brace as content, and the foreach loop is properly closed.